# Transforming/exporting text to image

Tags: export, text

I have a string in a .txt which I process as follow:

```
ks = Import["string.txt"];
Export["res", Style[ks, 8, Black, FontFamily -> "Courier"], "PNG", 
       ImageSize -> {8 sx, 4 sy}];

res = Import["res"];
Export["res.gif", res];
```

Here I have two problems. First, none of the monospaced fonts seems to make the end image look monospaced. (I believe this was somehow addressed in a previous question but no solution was found.) To get around this I thought for drawing the characters individually, but that would be resource-intensive. Is there a way to get real monospaced text from Wolfram?

The second problem is that the output images seem to have a fixed sized for the amount of characters that may fit in a line, therefore rendering partial lines of text. I think this is because of the way Mathematica imports the string but don't know how to solve it. An example is shown below.

I appreciate your help.

---

**Sample input:** http://pastebin.com/5ThLXw6L (Because it is long)

**Sample output:**

[image: Output]

**Which comes from:**

[image: Original input]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix that by adjusting `ItemSize` with `Grid`

```
txt = Import["5ThLXw6L.txt", "Table"];
data = Flatten[Map[Characters, txt], 1];

Export["txt.png", 
  Grid[Map[Style[#, 20, Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier"] &, data, {2}], 
  Spacings -> 0, ItemSize -> {1, 2}]]
```

[image]